# Sum of consecutive increment

Tags: javascript

I am trying to determine the increment that I would want to use to reach a specific number in a specific amount of iterations.

For example, my goal number is 100 and my starting number is 1. Which increment added to 1 each time would let me reach 100 in 10 iterations.

Something like x+(x+y)+(x+2y)+(x+3y)...+(x+9y)=100 where x=1 and y=my increment.

I have been playing around in javascript but I am at a loss.

Comment: Let me try to clarify my understanding here: you are trying to start at a basic step, x, to reach a goal number, 100, and are trying to write code that will solve for the value that will take the difference between 1 and 100 and divide it up into some even amount of steps?

Comment: @Jhecht Yes, a specific amount of steps. In my example, it was 10 steps.

Comment: `y = 2` => `100 - 10x - Sum(1..9)*y` => `90 = 45 * y`

Comment: @zerkms y shouldn't begin defined, y is what i'm looking for given my parameters.

Comment: y isn't defined, he is showing you how to solve for it based on the information. Give me a minute I'm writing something up. this is algebra work

Comment: @Jhecht Thank you. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Questions about general algebra aren't on–topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have make the math equation for this , it has to be generalised . Lets say

x id the starting number , y is what you have to find . n is iterations and g is your goal .

```
 n * x + (n *(n-1)/2) y = g
```

In your case you have n , x , g
hence 10 + 45 y = 100
gives you y = 2 .

so , the final equation is for solving y is

```
 y = (g - (n * x)) / (n *(n-1)/2)
```

Now you have to implement this equation in javascript and find y .

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your equation in x and y really reflects the problem statement that you've meant to put in English also, but assuming it does, then you can exhibit a simple arithmetic progression out of it, as:

(goal) G = x + (x + y) + (x + 2y) + (x + 3y) + ... + (x + (n - 1)y)

equiv.

G = n * x + (0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n - 1) * y

equiv.

G = n * x + (n * (n - 1) / 2) * y

equiv.

y = 2 * (G - n * x) / (n * (n - 1))

E.g., (as in your example)

y = 2 * (100 - 10) / (10 * 9) = 2

And, indeed:

100 = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + 15 + 17 + 19

'HTH,